# What is the command to highlight bad boxes in pdf?

Tags: boxes, warnings

I seem to remember a command to show bad boxes in a PDF when using latex, but googling is not helping me to remember.

How can I show bad boxes in my PDF?

Comment: add `draft` to the documentclass options.

Comment: Is there also an option for underfull hboxes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Pass the `draft` option to your document class or insert

```
\overfullrule=5pt
```

in your preamble. (Assuming that by *bad boxes* you mean *overfull boxes*.)

Comment: I vaguely recall some other command, but this certainly does the job. I may be thinking of the ConTeXt command.... who knows. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doesn't this solution only work for bad hboxes? The question suggests that the OP is also interested in highlighting bad vboxes, but neither the draft option nor `\overfullrule=5pt` in the preamble accomplishes this.